# How to align image and text exactly equal when using in gridview android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

Hi I am using `Gridview` to display images with text below by using custom adapter. But problem is when I fetch image and display, align gets changing and it's not proper.Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="3" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

**gridview.row:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" > 
 <RelativeLayout 
 android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/brand_picture"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/brand_name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/brand_picture"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="TextView"
 android:background="@color/blue"
 android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

How to achieve the expected output with same image size and text below that.

**Expected output is:**

[image]

**But my output looks like this.**
  [image]
  Thanks.

Comment: use height and width in imageview not wrap content

Comment: say for eg: if i set imageview as 80dp, 80 dp, it won't set for all device :(

Comment: check my ans...i hope it works for u..

Answer (score 0):

On setting  Wrap content the widget adjusts its height/width parameters to the given content size.so

change width of image view and text view from wrap content and set **same width for both image view and text view.**

eg:android:layout_width="70dp"

To get text in cente of text view you have to set
android:gravity="center"
**xml:ROW**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" > 
 <RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="#333333">
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/brand_picture"
   android:layout_width="90dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#499999" 
  android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/brand_name"
  android:layout_width="90dp"
   android:layout_below="@+id/brand_picture"
   android:gravity="center"
  android:text="AQUA LUNG"
  android:background="#445657"
  android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Comment: Did you give a try? .It worked for me.I have posted the modified code

Comment: He is just saying that it work work as in it wont fir all the screen sizes beause of fixed width

Answer (score 0):

try this..hope it works for u..

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/brand_picture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/brand_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/brand_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/brand_picture"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add property,

```
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

to your ImageView as well as TextView. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this layout:

Actually i have replaced your relative layout with linear layout, but it works just like what you want.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/brand_picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/brand_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this resolves your issue....

Comment: This wont help, still he will get the same output

Comment: still same output that looks small

Answer (score 0):

```
 <RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="#000000">
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/brand_picture"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/brand_name"
      android:layout_width="90dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/brand_picture"
      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/brand_picture"
      android:layout_below="@+id/brand_picture"
      android:background="#445657"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="WHATEVER"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Or You can try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" > 
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/brand_picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/brand_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Hopw this helps you